# ASP.NET/GridView: Using only a subset of the data fields in the table

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a list of objects called `Activity` and I want to display the date, type and notes for each and every one of these activities. This is the code I'm using.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTable" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" ShowHeader="true">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityDate" HeaderText="Date"
      HeaderStyle-CssClass="date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityType" HeaderText="Type" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityNotes" HeaderText="Notes" />
  </Columns>
  <PagerSettings Position="Bottom" Mode="NextPrevious" PageButtonCount="5"
    PreviousPageText="Older activities" NextPageText="Newer activities" />
</asp:GridView>
```

However, all of the attributes of each object is displayed in the header. How can I force it to display only the columns that I want to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gvTable.AutoGenerateColumns = false`

or

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="true" ShowHeader="true">
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Just a note, using capital `False` in C# code-behind may result in error.

Answer (score 3):

Set the attribute on your gridview:

```
AutoGenerateColumns="false"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the AutoGenerateColumns property on the grid to false.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried AutoGenerateColumns="false" in the gridview?